# How do I go back to original post after a clicking photo comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

When you click on a photo post on Facebook, it pops up the modal window. You can see the comments on the right. When people leave photo comments, and you click on them, how do you go back to the original photo/post you first opened?

**What I've tried**

- Hitting the Escape key doesn't work (closes the entire popup)
- Hitting the Backspace key doesn't work (closes the entire popup)
- Hitting left/right doesn't work (just scrolls through commenters posts)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could open in a new tab. But that can be a pain, especially when you already have dozens of tabs open.

Comment: you could press F5 fn key ,or go to your address bar and remove **&theater** at the end of the url and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to click anywhere outside of modal to get back to the original photo/post you first opened.

Comment: Absolutely not. This takes you out completely - also from the original post

Answer (score 0):

Press the Back button in the browser and then Refresh.

Answer (score -1):

[I believe it's impossible by design](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) - This link is to how the image object is trated on facebook, and as you can see it definitely allows a user to get all the comments from a photo. So, I can presume that FB **intentionally blocked and un-documented** this small glitch in order to protect some interest it has in people not getting back to original pictures via comments.

I imagine it has something to do with the way you are prevented from seeing content by people who have high privacy settings - comments are pretty much the only place where you can be exposed to these peoples comments. This is FB's way of making sure that if you got to the comment from a different source - say a share on a wall of a friend - you will not be able to see the actual picture.

Just a thought, though - **I don't work for FB.**